# Compute $a+b+c+d$ where $(ab+c+d =13),\ (bc+d+a = 27),\ (cd+a+b = 30),\ (da+b+c = 17)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, symmetry, cyclotomic-polynomials

Compute $(a+b+c+d)\ $ if $\ a,b,c,d\ $ satisfy the system of equations below:

$$\begin{cases}
ab+c+d = 13\\\\
bc+d+a = 27\\\\
cd+a+b = 30\\\\
da+b+c = 17
\end{cases}$$

.................................................................................My method:

I added all equations to get:

$(ab+bc+cd+da)+2(a+b+c+d)=87$

$(a+c)(b+d)+2(a+c)+2(b+d)=87$

$(a+c)(b+d+2)+2(b+d)=87$

$(a+c+2)(b+d+2)=91$

$(a+c+2)(b+d+2)=13\times 7$

So, $a+c=11$ and $b+d=5$

or, $a+c =5$ and $b+d =11$

Hence, $a+b+c+d = 16$

But I am not sure if this is the correct method since it was not stated that $a,b,c,d$ were positive integers.

I would be thankful if someone provided a solution to this question.

Comment: Please write the question in altex

Comment: You can also have $a+c+2 = 1$, $b+d+2=91$ which gives $a+b+c+d = 88$. You could even have $a+c+2 = -1, b+d+2 = -91$ or anything else as it is not given that $a,b,c,d$ are integers.

Comment: This question is poorly designed, as there is no way to determine which is the correct answer without a further condition. I would advise you to refuse to answer the question until it is properly defined.

Answer (score 5):

Let $u = a+b+c+d$, the set of equations can be rewritten as

$$
\begin{cases}
(a-1)(b-1) + a + b + c + d &= 14\\ 
(b-1)(c-1) + a + b + c + d &= 28\\
(c-1)(d-1) + a + b + c + d &= 31\\
(d-1)(a-1) + a + b + c + d &= 18
\end{cases}
\iff
\begin{cases}
(a-1)(b-1) &= 14- u\\
(b-1)(c-1) &= 28 -u\\
(c-1)(d-1) &= 31 -u\\
(d-1)(a-1) &= 18 -u
\end{cases}$$
This leads to

$$(14-u)(31-u) = (a-1)(b-1)(c-1)(d-1) = (28-u)(18-u)$$
which can be simplified to $u = 70$. So $a + b + c + d = 70$.

Comment: Nice trick to homogenize equations, frankly when you see it, this looks obvious, yet I was stuck on the problem without it...

Comment: But Wolfram get other [solutions](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/1.1605961675.png): $34$ and $\frac{2062}{121}$.

Comment: @DmitryEzhov  you have asked WA to solve the wrong set of equations, the coefficients in front of $ab, bc, cd, da$ should be $1$.

Comment: @achillehui Oh, sorry (I get system from title)